# What is the difference between = and => for a variable?

Tags: c#

What's the difference between these two ways to add something?

```
private string abc => "def";
```

And

```
private string abc = "def";
```

Comment: The first defines a private `get` property, the second a private field with an initial value

Comment: Funnily you can use the [tryroslyn](http://goo.gl/Ee1dXQ) to see the difference in the compiled-and-then-decompiled code between the two (on the right pane)

Comment: @Me.Name: Please do not write answers in the comments section.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the declaration of a classic **field** as it has always existed in C#:

```
private string abc = "def";
```

The field is immediately assigned an initial value.

---

This is a shorthand syntax for declaring a **getter-only property** (or *expression-bodied property*), introduced in C# 6:

```
private string abc => "def";
```

It's a short way to write the following:

```
private string abc
{
    get { return "def"; }
}
```

Comment: If you want an official source to read for this information, Allow me to provide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Comment: @DavidWatts That's not official source. It's just msdn magazine. Anyone can write there.

Comment: @DavidWatts It's actually SriramSakthivel who wrote the article under the alias "Mark Michaelis". Go figure...

Comment: Yes @YuvalItzchakov co-authored me :p

Comment: Ah, you learn something new every day eh!